# Expand the 'locked question' notice in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, locked-questions

In the StackExchange iOS app, a locked question shows a locked note in the title and a banner at the bottom:

[image]

In this case, with [this particular question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/wordpress-can-i-add-categories-tags-to-all-sites-in-my-network-at-once) I was about to flag it for a moderator and ask why it was locked, because there didn't seem to be anything wrong with it. I figured it might've just been leftover from the old days and could probably be unlocked now.

But then I realised I should probably open it in the browser first, just in case:

[image]

That definitely explains why it was locked!

In the case of duplicate questions, these are already well taken care of by the app, with a link to the duplicate(s) at the top of the question. In the case of locked, and perhaps merged, questions, this doesn't seem to be the case.

So my feature request is: **Can the 'locked' message be expanded in the iOS app to cover what a question is locked for?**

A fallback feature request if that's not easy/possible: could the Locked banner be linked to the question in the browser? (It's currently not linked anywhere)

Comment: A little background: neither of those notices are associated with the lock, it gets locked without any info. The app just needs to fetch and display merge and migration information.

Comment: @animuson Got it. Should I edit the feature request to cover that? Or would it be more useful for the app dev's as is? (don't want to unintentionally make an XY question)